# Detect UISearchBar focus on the text field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uisearchbar

Is there a way to detect if a user has click on the searchbar textfield and the keyboard has appear ?

Answer (score 12):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate),

- `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:`
- `searchBarCancelButtonClicked:`

Answer (score 11):

If you are implementing UISearchBarDelegate, the first method that should be called is:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {  
    //do stuff
    return YES;  
}
```

Here's the class reference:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBarShouldBeginEditing:

Comment: This doesn't always work. Namely, when user clicks Cancel button on the search bar (if it is visible) then the next time user clicks the search bar method searchBarShouldBeginEditing isn't called.

Answer (score 3):

Your searchbar delegate should receive a searchBarTextDidBeginEditing: message.