# Check for deselection in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I have a `UITableView` in the Master of a Master-Detail setup. Users can interact with the cell through `UITableViewRowAction`, or search using a given search bar.

When the user interacts with the search bar or slides the cell to the left, the cell is deselected. I need to be notified when a cell is deselected.

I tried `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` but it does not seem to respond **to situations like these**.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Cell Deselected")
}
```

This never executed on the conditions I've given above, but it does get executed only when a different item in the `tableView` is selected, **which is not what I need**.

Comment: Did you set and conform your delegate correctly ?

Comment: Yes. I've revised the question to be more clear.

Comment: Are you calling `tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)`?

Answer (score 0):

**Newer answer:**

You'll need to catch when other responders are selected outside of the table.

For example, [for going into edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1776117/981049):

```
func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    print("Cell deselected")
}
```

and [going into the search bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095909/detect-uisearchbar-focus-on-the-text-field), use this delegate method:

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(UISearchBar)
{
     print("Cell Deselected")
}
```

**Original answer:**

Make sure you set your view controller (or whatever object your `didDeselectRowAt` function lives in) as the table view's `delegate`. You can set that in your storyboard or you can do it programatically.

Comment: The delegate is set correctly. The deselect only gets called when you select a different item, but not when you perform actions like reloadData() or slide with `UITableViewRowAction`

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the **SelectedIndexPath** on the class level and when the user touches anywhere outside the table you can call this method like this:-

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: SelectedIndexPath, animated: true)
```

You can also receive call from:

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
}
```